# How do I batch files numbered/named in sequential order starting from 0 using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the command prompt to batch some image files from a video using FFMPEG . Right now I am using **%05d** to output all files named 00001, 00002, 00003, 00004, etc. However, I want to start at 00000. How can I do this so that files are batched and named starting at 0 instead of 1?

My line for the .jpg output looks like this :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-20190411-3e10223-win64-static\bin>ffmpeg -i C:\Users\user1\Desktop\imgs\testy2.mov -qscale:v 2 C:\Users\user1\Desktop\imgs\%05d.jpg
```

Comment: That's a big set of tags, and yet I have no idea what you're doing. Show some of your code.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes I'm a beginner so it may sound too simple. I just want to know if I can use the " %05d " format, in my jpeg path, but in a way that it will start at 0? I want to know how to change the jpeg path name so that all the jpegs will spit out starting at 0.

Comment: The cmd.exe (batch) programming language is not C. It does not use `%05d` as a formatter. Show a MCVS of your code. That is the only way someone will be able to help you without guessing in the wind.

Comment: `%05d` isn't a batch thing. In batch, `%0` translates to the batch file's name and `5d` will just be added as a string. Please clarify, what you use.

Comment: Wait, I see you changed tags from Java to something else. My previous comments ware about Java language, so I will remove them.

Comment: Sorry, I should be clear that I'm using a software called ffmpeg in the command line that uses C..so my jpeg output above works in the command line because of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-start_number` [image muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) output option:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-20190411-3e10223-win64-static\bin>ffmpeg -i C:\Users\user1\Desktop\imgs\testy2.mov -qscale:v 2 -start_number 0 C:\Users\user1\Desktop\imgs\%05d.jpg
```